# How to color different groups in qqplot?

Tags: r

I'm plotting some Q-Q plots using the qqplot function. It's very convenient to use, except that I want to color the data points based on their IDs. For example:

```
library(qualityTools)
n=(rnorm(n=500, m=1, sd=1) )
id=c(rep(1,250),rep(2,250))
myData=data.frame(x=n,y=id)
qqPlot(myData$x, "normal",confbounds = FALSE)
```

So the plot looks like:
[image]

I need to color the dots based on their "id" values, for example blue for the ones with id=1, and red for the ones with id=2. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: check out http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/car/docs/qqPlot palette and par and col of course (color for points)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not used qqPlot before, but it you want to use it, there is a way to achieve  what you want.  It looks like the function invisibly passes back the data used in the plot.  That means we can do something like this:

```
# Use qqPlot - it generates a graph, but ignore that for now
plotData <- qqPlot(myData$x, "normal",confbounds = FALSE, col = sample(colors(), nrow(myData)))

# Given that you have the data generated, you can create your own plot instead ...
with(plotData, {
  plot(x, y, col = ifelse(id == 1, "red", "blue"))
  abline(int, slope)
})
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can try setting `col = myData$y`. I'm not sure how the `qqPlot` function works from that package, but if you're not stuck with using that function, you can do this in base R.

Using base R functions, it would look something like this:

```
# The example data, as generated in the question
n <- rnorm(n=500, m=1, sd=1)
id <- c(rep(1,250), rep(2,250))
myData <- data.frame(x=n,y=id)

# The plot
qqnorm(myData$x, col = myData$y)
qqline(myData$x, lty = 2)
```

[image]

Not sure how helpful the colors will be due to the overplotting in this particular example.

Comment: thanks much. you are right coloring the dots in this case is not useful. I provided only a simple example. Currently I'm using a big dataset which I was not able to provide hear in SO. The purpose of the study is to see what feature is causing the data points to not fit the Normal line. In the above plot, for example the tails are not following the Gaussian distribution, so what is the cause? That's the purpose of this study. Thank you anyway.

Comment: how about for other distributions, like weibull? should I use qqweibull? thanks